# jQuery Resizeable With Cookie For Remembering Last Position

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery UI resizeable. It works great.

But now I want to set cookie in there function, so if I refresh the page it will set the last position that I resized before.

the JS call function :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#resizable").resizable();
});
```

Please help to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jquery Cookie plugn for this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(typeof($.cookie('height')!='undefined'))
   {
       $("#resizable").height($.cookie("height"));
       $("#resizable").width($.cookie("width"));
   }
   $("#resizable" ).resizable({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          var width = ui.size.width;
          var height = ui.size.height;
          $.cookie("height",height);
          $.cookie("width",width);
    }
  });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMN7G/114/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. 1 question, why when I refresh page, width not fixed with our resized. Please see when you refresh.

Comment: @hiDayurie its working fine on my local use it in your website jsfidller use iframe may be this is the reason.

Comment: I tried in My local. Same problem. When I resized the div(assuming using div), it resized. But When I refresh the page the resized div will add a bit of width.